# Probably Tappet noise in my brand new yamaha fz fi

Tags: yamaha, valve, india

Little Tappet noise from my brand new bike i.e yamaha fz fi india. Svc guys told me it require valve clearance adjustment. My question is, is it ok for brand new bike to adjust valve clearance on its first service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course. The valve clearances may move during first usage period as they settle. It is fine to adjust the valve clearances and the tappet noise should reduce. Excessive tappet noise can be caused by a stiff/sticky rocker arm and this could be a fault with your engine. Have the clearances adjusted and see if the noise goes.

Comment: Yes, part of the "running in" process..